# Unable to fetch data from a view that accesses data over db link

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, distributed-computing

I have a query to fetch data from two tables over a db link as below:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME, b.address
  FROM table1@dblink a, table2@dblink b
 WHERE a.ID = b.ID;
```

This works perfectly fine. Then I create a view for this as below:

```
CREATE VIEW myview
AS
   SELECT a.ID, a.NAME, b.address
     FROM table1@dblink a, table2@dblink b
    WHERE a.ID = b.ID;
```

View is created successfully. But when I select data from the view as below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myview
```

I get error like:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-02063: preceding line from MYLINK
```

What could probably be the issue?

EDIT:

Tried different methods and ended up getting different error. Here I am posting the exact query and the latest error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW plan_view
AS
   WITH plan_name AS
        (SELECT     fcr.argument1 AS plan_name, fcr.request_id AS request_id
               FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_requests@dblink fcr
              WHERE argument1 IN
                             ('E10', 'E20', 'E40', 'E60L', 'EDC', 'PS1', 'S')
         CONNECT BY PRIOR fcr.request_id = fcr.parent_request_id
         START WITH request_id =                                 -- '58043920'
                       (SELECT MAX (request_id) AS request_id
                          FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_requests@dblink
                         WHERE description = 'Mail Program'
                           AND actual_start_date >=
                                  TO_DATE (   TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1),
                                                       'mm-dd-yyyy'
                                                      )
                                           || '05:00:00 PM',
                                           'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'
                                          )
                           AND actual_start_date < SYSDATE)),
        e10 AS
        (SELECT     TRIM
                       (BOTH ' ' FROM (SELECT meaning
                                         FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values@dblink
                                        WHERE lookup_type = 'CP_STATUS_CODE'
                                          AND lookup_code = fcr.status_code
                                          AND view_application_id = 0)
                       ) status,
                    TRIM
                       (BOTH ' ' FROM (SELECT meaning
                                         FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values@dblink
                                        WHERE lookup_type = 'CP_PHASE_CODE'
                                          AND lookup_code = fcr.phase_code
                                          AND view_application_id = 0)
                       ) phase,
                    fcr.request_id AS rid,
                    fcr.actual_start_date AS start_date,
                    fcr.actual_completion_date AS completion_date
               FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_requests@dblink fcr
         CONNECT BY PRIOR fcr.request_id = fcr.parent_request_id
         START WITH request_id = (SELECT request_id
                                    FROM plan_name
                                   WHERE plan_name IN ('E10')))
   SELECT 'E10' "PLAN_NAME", (SELECT MIN (start_date)
                                FROM e10) "START_DATE",
          (SELECT COUNT (rid)
             FROM e10)
     FROM DUAL
```

When I try selecting directly from the query I get proper output. But after I create the view and try `select * from plan_view` I get the below error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00904: "FCR"."REQUEST_ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: @zephrus:If you are creating view ,then why not view on remote database and then access view using db link?

Comment: That is actually the issue here. I cannot create a view in the parent DB - like some internal policies. And this view created in the second Database will be accessed by other DB as well over dblinks.

Comment: You should also be getting this error: `ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias`, since the third column does not have a name.  You may want to shrink your sample code to the smallest possible example that still throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the old problem with granting privileges.  For ad hoc DML (select, insert, etc) we can use privileges granted through a role.  But to build permanent objects - views, stored procedures, etc - we must have privileges granted to the user directly.

So, the most common explanation for the phenomenon you describe is that the tables' owner  has granted rights on those tables to a role not to you.